# What is the current state of AI regarding features of Moravec's paradox, such as sensorimotor & perception skills?

Tags: reference-request, robotics, state-of-the-art

[Moravec's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moravec%27s_paradox) is the observation in artificial intelligence and robotics that, contrary to traditional assumptions, reasoning requires very little computation, but sensorimotor and perception skills require enormous computational resources.

Given that there have been strong advancements in computer vision in the past few years, what is the current state of AI when it comes to giving a physical robot the possibility of identifying and performing unstructured physical tasks in the real world?